# Hello World not working for C# on cloud9

Tags: c#, reference, sdk, mscorlib, cloud9

How do I reference `mscorlib` for C# in cloud9?

The sample code for hello world doesn't work

```
using System;

public class Hello2
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
   }
}
```

because it emits the following errors:

> error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘System’ using System;
>       error: ‘System’ has not been declared
>        error: expected unqualified-id before ‘public’
>        public class Hello2

Comment: just right click references, there you can see in existing assemblies mscorlib

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `namespace`

```
using System;
namespace namespace_name
{
   public class Hello2
   {
       public static void Main()
       {
             Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘System’
 using System;       error: ‘System’ has not been declared     error: expected ‘{’ before ‘public’
 public class Hello2   error: expected unqualified-id before ‘public’     error: expected ‘}’ at end of input